# jQuery.crSpline and animation callback

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-plugins

I'm building many animations using [jQuery.crSpline](https://github.com/MmmCurry/jquery.crSpline) plugin and on the animation I need to add a callback and it seems to not fire up..

This is part of my method:

```
if(_self.okBack == 'no') {
            $(id)
                .not(':animated')
                .appendTo($(layerId))
                .addClass('mover')
                .stop(true, true)
                .animate({ crSpline: spline }, {duration: speed, queue: false }, easing, function() {
                    alert('done');
                    _self.okBack = 'yes';
                });
        }
```

no alert and no property changes...

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is:

```
.animate({ crSpline: spline }, { duration: speed, queue: false, easing: easing, complete: function() {
    _self.okBack = 1;   
}});
```